# Link click tracking on dynamic content after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I track links clicked on my page with some jquery like so:

```
// Track when a visitor clicks a link
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // Add an event handler to all body anchor links
    $( "body" ).find("a").click(function() {  
        ga('send', 'event', document.title, 'Link: ' + this.innerHTML, '');
    });
```

});

This works very well for static page content.  However, some of my pages load in partial page content dynamically from elsewhere on my site using Jquery load() method.  e.g. $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );

I have noticed that when I click on a link on this dynamic content, the link isn't getting tracked in GA.

I guess this makes sense, the link event handlers are added when the page is **initially** loaded, any content pulled through after this won't have these event handlers registered...

So my question is, how do i track links clicked for content that is added dynamically after the page has loaded? Should I add my event handler code (above) to a function which i can call on page load then after any dynamic content has been added, telling it to scan the page again?  Will that cause a conflict with any original event handlers or will it override them?

thanks

Comment: See section 'Delegated events' on http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks, Delegated events works ok  $( "body" ).on( "click", "a", function() {